# Created predicate doesn't work in Linq to Entity Framework Where clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'd like to move predicate building logic into a base class and am getting the error “The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities”.  I want to be able to concatenate or conditionally chain the expressions in the predicate.

I want to be able to pass in the part of the predicate that is unique to the caller which is the property names used (the **GetFilterPredicate** will become a generic routine which will operate on types that will have different property names holding the relevant values).

```
        protected Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> GetFilterPredicate(
        PagingParameters pagingParameters,
        Func<MyEntity, DateTime?> terminationDate,
        Func<MyEntity, string> entityID,
        Func<MyEntity, string> name
        )
    {
        Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> validFilter = x => true;

        if (pagingParameters.Active == true)
        {
            validFilter = x => terminationDate(x) > DateTime.Now;
        }

        ///more conditions added here

        return validFilter;
    }

    protected List<MyEntity> Query(IQueryable<MyEntity> source)
    {
        var filters = GetFilterPredicate(
            new PagingParameters() { Active = true }
            , i => i.TerminationDate
            , i => i.EntityID
            , i => i.Name
            );

        return source.Where(filters).AsNoTracking().ToList<MyEntity>();
    }
```

Comment: I think you left out the relevant part, what you are doing with `Func<MyEntity, string> entityID,` et al. They should be `Expression<>`s too.

Comment: EF can't invoke the function terminationDate(x) within its sql computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't construct your new expression using the delegate `terminationDate` you need to change `terminationDate` to be an Expression and use it to build a new expression manually.

```
protected static  Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> GetFilterPredicate(
    PagingParameters pagingParameters,
    Expression<Func<MyEntity, DateTime?>> terminationDate,
    Expression<Func<MyEntity, string>> entityID,
    Expression<Func<MyEntity, string>> name
)
{
    Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> validFilter = x => true;
    // We need to replace the parameter for all expressions with 
    // a common single parameter. I used the parameter for the default
    // filter but a new Parameter expression would have worked as well.
    // If you don't do this you will get an error (unbound parameter or something like that ) because the parameter  
    // used in the expressions (terminationDate, entityID) will be 
    // different then the parameter used for the new validFilter expression
    var parameterReplacer = new ReplaceVisitor
    {
        NewParameter = validFilter.Parameters.First()
    };

    if (pagingParameters.Active == true)
    {
        validFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>(
            Expression.GreaterThan
            (
                parameterReplacer.Visit(terminationDate.Body),
                Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(null, typeof(DateTime), "Now"), typeof(DateTime?))
            ),
            parameterReplacer.NewParameter
        );
    }

    // existing filter && x.EntityId != "A"
    validFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>(
            Expression.And(
                validFilter.Body,
                Expression.NotEqual
                (
                    parameterReplacer.Visit(entityID.Body),
                    Expression.Constant("A")
                )
            ),
            parameterReplacer.NewParameter
        );

    return validFilter;
}
/// <summary>
/// Simple Parameter Replacer, will replace the any parameter with the new
/// parameter. You will need to refine this if your expressions have nested 
/// lambda, in that you will need to only replace the top most lambda 
/// parameter, but for simple expressions it will work fine.
/// </summary>
class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression NewParameter { get; set; }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return this.NewParameter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like a winner - will verify by Monday if not sooner. Not exactly intuitive!  Do you know of any good sites with more info on building Linq expressions? Ones I've found don't have anything this advanced.

Comment: @dr3x Sorry, I don't have any detailed references, I'm mostly self-taught when it comes to this topic. When I first started, I would write a similar expression in code and then used the debugger to see what the generated expression tree looked like and started from there. I will add some more comments to the answer maybe it helps.

Comment: Note that because you use `Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now)` the generated query will not be the same. If you use `DateTime.Now` in expression - EF will translate that in `SYSDATETIME()` sql function. But if you use constant - that will be just `>= 'explicit date and time here'`. Better use `Expression.Property(null, typeof(DateTime), "Now")`

Comment: @Evk yes you are right, functionally it does almost the same thing, but for plan caching, there might be performance implications. Updated to reflect your feedback, 10x.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually as Titian answer describes, but easier way is to use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). First install LinqKit nuget package and add `using LinqKit;`, then:

```
// change terminaionDate to Expression<Func<MyEntity, DateTime>>
static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> GetFilterPredicate(Expression<Func<MyEntity, DateTime>> terminationDate) {
    // note Invoke
    Expression<Func<Error, bool>> filter = c => terminationDate.Invoke(c) <= DateTime.Now;
    // note Expand
    return filter.Expand();
}
```

You can read about `Invoke` and `Expand` at the link provided above.

Comment: Thanks - very concise, but I'm trying to avoid external dependencies, even if it takes a lot more to code so will go with the manual route if it works.

Comment: If you are going to use that a lot - might be better to just include source code of LinqKit to your own project (its license allows that), because reinventing it or writing queries manually might take a lot of useless efforts.